# Why can I not use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in remote desktop anymore?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I use Remote Desktop. Before, I always copied my files through Remote Desktop. But since yesterday, this is not working anymore. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Maybe it's because yesterday I've switched from HDD to SSD. Or, was there a Remote Desktop update? Maybe I need to change something in the settings.

I tried already some settings but I found nothing.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: @Burgi Windows Server 2012 R2, it seems.

Comment: @FleetCommand not sure how I missed that

Comment: Possible work-around (for text): Shift-Del to cut, Shift-Insert to paste (do this right away, to effectively be a "copy" rather than a cut -- then do this again where-ever else you want to paste)

Answer (score 9):

1. Start Task Manager on Remote Desktop.
2. End the process rdpclip.exe
3. Start Run (via start menu)
4. Write "rdpclip.exe"
5. Enter

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, if you are using the built-in remote desktop program, the only thing you need is a checkbox under the resources tab that allows the clipboard to be shared between machines. Be sure that is checked.

[image: clipboard]

Also, since you stated that you got a new SSD, the drive letter may have changed. To check that, click "more" and then make sure that all of the drives are checked.

[image: more]

Comment: Still doesn not work

Comment: You might have an application that "hijacks" your CTRL+C - and then interfere with the RDP session - so check if you have a clipboard extender app running.

Comment: What happens if you drag a file from the remote machine's desktop to yours? (Un-full screen the remote desktop window to do this) Do you get a red X indicator or does it transfer successfully?

Comment: I get a x, When i do that

Comment: Click on the "more" button as shown in the above screenshot. Are all the drives checked?

Comment: Yes, All thing are checked but i dont see CopierStore

Comment: Ours will not be the same. That is a shared drive on my network.

Comment: Ok, Still not working my copy

Comment: On the remote session, open up task manager and view the current running processes. Look for one called rdclip.exe. Is it there?

Comment: Another common usability problem with CTRL-C, CTRL-V is that there can be a delay between CTRL-C and the clipboard being populated depending on your RDP connection. Pressing CTRL-V too early will actually cancel the CTRL-C operation rather than queuing the CTRL-V thus the appearance CTRL-C didn't work. I generally find right-click -> Copy then right-click -> Paste is a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote machine is not under your control (EG If it's on a domain) this might have been restricted by the administrator's Group Policy Object setting here...

Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection > "Do not allow Clipboard redirection"

You have no visibility into this from the client side, so you would need to ask your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

What if the Clipboard works but just the keyboard shortcuts don't work. You can right click to select copy using your mouse but the Keyboard shortcuts(Ctrl-c/v) are not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1206387)